# How to test rkhunter to make sure its functioning well?

Tags: malware, antivirus, rootkit, rkhunter

I have a Ubuntu 15.10 Linux laptop PC with rkhunter installed now all I need to do is to confirm it working well like if there is an antivirus on your pc you will go to the eicar site and download the test file or you test a firewall with sheildsup but how do you test a root kit scanner like rkhunter with?

Comment: You actually have to set up rkhunter BEFORE you are infected, when you have a known clean system.  You then run scans and compare it with the 'clean' state to determine if you have any system infections or compromises in it.

Comment: I just installed a fresh one yesterday

Comment: Then you record the current state of the machine, then later run rkhunter and compare to see if there were any changes.  Sometimes changes happen due to software updates, so you have to keep track of those - that's the only real way to determine if rkhunter is working.

Comment: What?  In English please

Comment: If you don't understand what I'm trying to say (SCAN when the system is clean.  SAVE logs.  Run rkhunter later, save those results.  COMPARE those results from the CLEAN SCAN items, any changes may indicate infections or changes done by system updates), then you should not be using rkhunter, likely.

Comment: Ok I get it so scan the system on the first time I installed Ubuntu and then after scan the system after I installed the software and updates then compare the results

Comment: Basically, yes.